# Is the regular group action of $G$ on itself doubly transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

Is the action of $G$ on itself ($X=G$) via left multiplication doubly transitive?

(I know it's transitive but can't figure out how to prove or disprove $2$-transitivity)

Edit -
Doubly transitive - For any $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2 \in X$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ and $y_1\neq y_2$, there exists some $g\in G$ such that $gx_1=y_1$ and $gx_2=y_2$. See: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Doubly_transitive_group_action

Comment: I'd link or quote a [definition of doubly transitive](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Doubly_transitive_group_action).

Comment: Yes, if $G$ has exactly two elementgs. No otherwise. I'll let you try to figure out how to prove it, as it is fairly straightforward.

Comment: I think it's easiest to use this characterisation of doubly transitive: $G$ is transitive on $\Omega$, and a stabilizer $G_\alpha$ is transitive on $\Omega\setminus\{\alpha\}$. As the stabilizer of $1$ is $\{1\}$ it's clear we get double transitivity only when $|G|=2$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: If $y_1 = g x_1$, $y_2 = g x_2$, then
$$y_1^{-1} y_2 = x_1^{-1} x_2$$

( like the "vectors" $x_1 x_2$ and $y_1 y_2$ are equal)

Answer (score 1):

The regular action is not just transitive, it's *sharply* transitive. That means, given any $x,y\in G$ there exists a *unique* group element $g\in G$ for which $y=gx$. There is no wiggle room in the choice of $g$! And thus, if there is more than one choice of where we might want to simultaneously send a second element to, we will not be able to realize all these destinations since there is only one travel option, $g$, to work with! This occurs if $|G|>2$.

In particular, the only element of $G$ that sends the identity element $e\in G$ to $g\in G$ is $g$ itself. If we have a second element $x\in G$, the only place it could also be sent then is to $gx$, not to any other element. Since $x$ is distinct from $e$, we can say $gx$ is distinct from $x$, and if there were any third element $y\ne g,gx$ that would mean it's impossible to arrange for $e\mapsto g,x\mapsto y$ since $e\mapsto g$ automatically implies $x\mapsto gx$ in the regular representation.